# Meta-swupdate yocto gub instead of u-boot bootloader

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I want to use the swupdate meta layer in my yocto build framework. see: https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate
Before I build it with `bitbake swupdate`I do some configuration with `bitbake -c menuconfig swupdate` here I can find some configuration for change the bootloader from u-boot to grub. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WDPT.png)

Anytime when I call `bitbake swupdate`the recipies u-boot is building...
If I start only the `bitbake u-boot` I get an error:

> Configuration file ".config" not found!

But there is no option `bitbake -c menuconfig u-boot`

I'm confused. Is there another .config file for u-boot?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the `swupdate` recipe is correct, the `DEPENDS` variable is automatically appended depending on the content of the `defconfig` file that is specified in `SRC_URI` or in config fragments[1]. Therefore, in order to remove `u-boot` from the `DEPENDS` variable, one needs to remove it from the `defconfig` that is unpacked in the recipe workdir. Running the `menuconfig` task won't probably be enough. One can probably remove U-Boot from the `defconfig` by running the `menuconfig` task, get the resulting `defconfig` output from the workdir and add it in a bbappend of the `swupdate` recipe.

[1] https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate/blob/master/recipes-support/swupdate/swupdate.inc#L90-L150